# Every Struts2 action I target fails

Tags: struts2, scope-strategy

Struts2 Scope Plugin is no longer compatible with the latest version of Struts2-core (e.g. 2.3.15). What is the successor of the Struts2 Scope Plugin? Struts2 Conversation Scope Plugin? What is the migration effort? Experience?

Comment: Did you found a solution. I'm running in the same issue now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is the Struts2 Conversation Plugin. There is nothing such as a migration plan.

Best strategy is to identify annotations from the old scope plugin. Then replace the them one-by-one with the new annotations.  E.g. Find @In/@Out annotations and replace them with @ConversationField (of course, where appropriate)

Follow the Quick-Intro here: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-conversation/

Answer (score 0):

First I tried to update the scope plugin itself. This is pretty straight forward (change dependency, add a version to the maven compiler, replace `findAnnotatedMethods` by  `getAnnotatedMethods` and fix the tests) and seems to work fine.

Nevertheless I decided to remove the plugin completely and use a simple `SessionAware` actions.